# Southside vs South side

Tags: grammar, word-order, capitalization

OK, I need some help with something that's been bugging me.
Google docs and MS docs both disagree with this, so I figured it was time to bring it to the pros:

When talking about Chicago, is it:
"Southside of Chicago",
"South side of Chicago",
"south side of Chicago", or
"southside of Chicago" (this one's even wrong according to this site).

Same question when putting "Chicago" first in line (Chicago's South side...)

Comment: Press releases on the City of Chicago's own website employ both *South Side* and *Southside* both nominally and attributively, but the two-word version is far more frequent. The *Tribune* seems to employ the two-word version consistently. Note, however, that both terms are capitalized: *Chicago's South Side*; and parts of the *South Side* are also capitalized: *the Far South Side*.

Comment: What do you mean "this one's even wrong according to this site?" This site doesn't vet what you type: your browser's doing that. We actually need to know what you mean by "Southside" -- is that the actual name of an area of Chicago, or merely a directional indication?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a first rule, *never* rely on machine spell-checkers (or grammar-checkers); at best, they are literally a call to *check* on the wording or spelling to make sure it is in fact what you intended. Second, please remember to demonstrate your initial attempts at research; for example, what does a web search show? Third, and what you really wanted to know, *South Side* is the name of a specific neighborhood of Chicago on the south side of the Loop, but other cities have *Southside* neighborhoods in their southside on the south side of town.

Comment: @choster Good point; my own hometown had the *Southside* shopping area, consisting of a laundromat, a mom-and-pop grocery store, a grill and a filling station.

Comment: @StoneyB Los Angeles has a *Westside*, but no *Eastside*; Miami has an *Upper Eastside* but no *Upper Westside*; Manhattan has both an *East Side* and *West Side* as well as an *Upper East Side* and *Upper West Side*. In Pittsburgh, it's the *North Side* and *South Side*, but *East End* and *West End*, while Boston has a *North End*, *South End*, and *West End*, but an *East Boston*. Pattern-seekers, thy bane is geography.

Comment: @choster Or indeed, *South side* or *south side* would simply mean the southern quadrant or southern extremity of the city. **If** this question is general, it needs more detail about what is actually meant; if it's specific to Chicago, then it needs more detail about Chicago (and looking up that detail will probably answer the question).

Comment: @AndrewLeach According to Wikipedia "It is one of the three major parts of the city, the others being the West Side and the North Side." And I see now that the *Far South Side* may not be a part of the South Side but a term referring collectively to the *Far Southeast Side* and *Far Southwest Side*.

Comment: Well there we go. Why isn't that research in the question?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Still a bit confusing though, especially as the rules have tended to change some since I was in elementary school, lol. for instance, I remember learning that the directions on a compass should be capitalized, hence my confusion of not capitalizing "South" when "South side".
I can see how "Southside" would make sense when used in a name or title of a store, for instance.

Maybe some sentences will help: 
1) My friend is working with kids on Chicago's South side (or Southside?).
2) My friend is working with kids on the South side of Chicago.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm pretty sure that if it is a noun it is two words and if it is an adjective, it is one word.

The South Side of Chicago is a noun. A southside Chicago shopping center would use southside as an adjective to describe the shopping center.

Comment: Hello, Audra. Is that a referential 'So' or not? Either way, Stoney B's 'comment' is far better referenced, yet as he merely mentions results without attributing, he restricts himself to a 'comment' here.